# A random variable $Y$ is $\mathcal F_T$-measurable IFF $Y1_{\{T=n\}}$ is $\mathcal F_n$-measurable for all $n \in \mathbb N$

Tags: probability-theory, stopping-times

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $\left(\mathcal{F}_n, n \in \mathbb N\right)$ a filtration. Let $T$ be a stopping time with respect to $\left(\mathcal{F}_n, n \in \mathbb{N}\right)$. One defines the information one possesses at time $T$ as the following $\sigma$-field:
$$
\mathcal{F}_T := \left\{A \in \mathcal{F}: A \cap\{T=n\} \in \mathcal{F}_n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}.
$$

I would like to verify below result, i.e.,

> **Theorem** A random variable $Y$ is $\mathcal F_T$-measurable IFF $Y1_{\{T=n\}}$ is $\mathcal F_n$-measurable for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Could you have a check on my below attempt?

---

**Proof** Fix $B \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.

1. Let $Y$ be $\mathcal F_T$-measurable. We want to prove $\{Y1_{\{T=n\}} \in B\} \in \mathcal F_n$. Indeed,
   $$
   \{Y1_{\{T=n\}} \in B\} =  (\{Y\in B\} \cap \{T=n\}) \cup (\{T \neq n\} 1_{\{0 \in B\}}) \in \mathcal F_n.
   $$
2. Let $Y1_{\{T=n\}}$ be $\mathcal F_n$-measurable for all $n \in \mathbb N$. We want to prove $\{Y \in B\} \cap \{T=n\}$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Indeed,
   $$
   \{Y \in B\} \cap \{T=n\} = \{Y1_{\{T=n\}} \in B\} \setminus (\{T \neq n\} 1_{\{0 \in B\}}) \in \mathcal F_n.
   $$

Comment: What does $A\mathbf{1}_B$ mean? One is a set, the other a function

Comment: @Snoop Ah I meant $\{T \neq n\} 1_{\{0 \in B\}} = \{T \neq n\}$ if $0\in B$ and $\emptyset$ otherwise. With this notation, do you feel my proof is fine?

Comment: You have to assume that $Y$ is $\mathcal{F}_\infty$-measurable: in the definition of $\mathcal{F}_T$, replace $\mathcal{F}$ by $\mathcal{F}_\infty$.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan My definition of $\mathcal F_T$ is *Definition 13.7.* from [this](https://ipgold.epfl.ch/~leveque/Lecture_Notes/APA_lecture_notes_1920.pdf) note. In this Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-Algebra_of_%CF%84-past), they still use $A \in \mathcal F$ as in my lecture note. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: I think in the last row you have an additional $\mathbf{1}_{\{0\in B\}}$. Is it a typo?

Comment: @Snoop Assume $0 \in B$. Then $\{T \neq n\} \subset \{Y1_{\{T=n\}} \in B\}$ but $\{T \neq n\} \not \subset (\{Y \in B\} \cap \{T=n\})$. That's why I have to remove this set if $0 \in B$.

Comment: What about this for (2):

$(\Leftarrow)$. Suppose $Y\mathbf{1}_{\{T=n\}}$ is $\mathscr{F}_n$-measurable $\forall n$. Then
$$\{Y \in B\}\cap\{T=n\}=\{Y\mathbf{1}_{\{T=n\}}\in B\}\cap\{T=n\}\in \mathscr{F}_n,\,\forall n$$
So $\{Y \in B\}\in \mathscr{F}_T,\,\forall B\in \mathscr{B}$. But then $Y$ is $\mathscr{F}_T$-measurable.

Comment: @Snoop Yess, it's much cleaner.

Comment: @Analyst In french wikipedia page https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temps_d%27arr%C3%AAt the condition $A \in \mathcal{F}_T$ is given in the diefinition. This condition is important to have the property $\mathcal{F}_S \subset \mathcal{F}_T$ whenever $S \subset T$, even if $+\infty$ is a possible value of $S$.